# Google Oauth 2.0 Web API redirect_uri_mismatch - Google redirecting the wrong URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Google API login for Google sheets in asp.net c# project but getting `redirect_uri_mismatch` error 400. I didn't even set this redirect URL which Google  is redirecting to. I have set redirect url `http://127.0.0.1:63092/login.aspx` but Google is redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:13557/authorize/` wrong port and wrong web page. My `Credential.json` also not having anything like `/authorize/` as you can see below.

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "client_idxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "app-xxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "secret_xxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "http://127.0.0.1:63092/login.aspx" ],
    "javascript_origins": [ "http://127.0.0.1:63092" ]
  }
}
```

On every try, it changes the port on `127.0.0.1` and redirecting to `/authorize/` what could be the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**My Code**

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
static string ApplicationName = "My App";
static string thisDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream =
    new FileStream(thisDir + "credential.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = thisDir + "token.json";
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }

    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

    String spreadsheetId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    String range = "Sheet1";
    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
            service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
    ValueRange response = request.Execute();
    IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
    if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
        foreach (var row in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to show your code. Show the full URL that you are calling to start the OAuth flow. Double check the `redirect_uri` in that URL.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated the question with my code. I am using online .Net examples for Google API

Comment: You are using the wrong type of Google Credential. In the Google Credentials console, select "Other" for the Application Type. Download the new credentials and try again.

Comment: What is the link to the example you are using? I might want to code up a test. Sometimes documents/examples go out of date or need updating.

Comment: @JohnHanley Let me try with "Other" and I am using https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks so much, it's working fine with "Other", I created new credentials with "Other". But I have a question why it isn't working with Web Application? Thanks again

Comment: DId you research the differences? One is for applications. The other is for a web server. The differences lie in how the redirect_uri is handled.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yeah I just finished reading the differences, Please suggest the answer so I can accept, Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google offers serveral credential types for different application usage. In your case, you are using credentials designed for web servers instead of credentials designed for installed applications (running locally at someone's desktop).

In the Google Credentials console, select "Other" for the Application Type. Download the new credentials and try again.